# How to hyperlink the text files into HTML file using R?

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, text-files

I have an HTML output file and there is a column named "Description" in this file. I want to link locally saved text files to some of the entries of this column when a value is `Report data does not match`.

Snapshot the HTML file is following: [image: HTML Output File]

So, there are dedicated texts files to `row no: 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`, which I want to link them to the `Description` column.

Line of Codes to generating HTML file is:

`library(xtable)
extract1 <- result[,list(TestCaseID, breadcrumb, Discription),]
print(xtable(extract1), type = "html", file = "extracted.html")`

How to do the linking of text files. Please let me know if any modification required in the question.  Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you perform a pre-processing according to your requirements. Because the names of the text files may change later, they should be provided as a separate column.

If the text file link is not required think of a conditional processing for NA's later.

The sample below is based on a main list. Text files reside in a subfolder.

The trick is the use of HTML tag `href` and use of the `sanitize.text.function` as shown below for your test cases.

You'll need to create some dummy text files like *gauge-D00.txt*, *gauge-D01.txt*, etc. in a subfolder to try the example.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
# gauge main ID list
#---------------------------------------------------------
# ID,location,description,textfile
# D00,nature reserve,Otternhagener Moor,../gauge-D00.txt
# D01,nature reserve,Helstorfer Moor,../gauge-D01.txt
# FER,benchmark,Negenborner Weg,../gauge-FER.txt                        
#----------------------------------------------------------
# text files reside in /data-develop-text-file-link/
# ---------------------------------------------------------
library (xtable)

gaugelist <- structure(list(
  ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("D00", "D01", "FER"), class = "factor"),
  location = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("benchmark", "nature reserve"), class = "factor"),
  description = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Helstorf", "Negenborn", "Otternhagen"), class = "factor"),
  textfile = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("../gauge-FER.txt", "../gauge-D00.txt", "../gauge-D01.txt"), class = "factor")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)) 
head(gaugelist)

# set HTML tag for linking to local file  -------------------------------------------- 
gaugelist$description <- paste("<a href=", gaugelist$textfile, ">", gaugelist$description, "</a>")
head(gaugelist)

# remove textfile column from data.frame --------------
gaugelist$textfile <- NULL
head(gaugelist)

# print HTML table and sanitize by using your own function (add subfolder) ---------------------------------------
print(xtable(gaugelist), type = "html", 
      sanitize.text.function = function(str) gsub("..", "./data-develop-text-file-link", str, fixed = TRUE), 
      file = "gauge-list.html")
```

**Edit:**

It is slightly better to reference the current directory `./data-develop-text-file-link` with `./`. I edited this for `gsub` handling but this makes no difference.

The structure of HTML and text files described in my answer above and only exemplarily hinted at as a thought is based on a website structure. The HTML table is located at any root node and the text files are located in a directory below it. So there is later the possibility to upload the file to a server or to leave it locally on the PC.

That's why I worked with relative links, which work for me in all browsers.

Please note that absolute paths to text files seem to be a problem with Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer. TEST: Copy the link with the right mouse button and paste it into Edge's address text box and the text file will open. I couldn't find any problems with Firefox and Chrome when testing with e.g. C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents or D:_working\ e.g.:

```
# print HTML table and sanitize by using your own function (add subfolder) ---------------------------------------
print(xtable(gaugelist), type = "html", 
      sanitize.text.function = function(str) gsub("..", "file:///C:/Users/webma/Documents/data-develop-text-file-link", str, fixed = TRUE), 
      file = "gauge-list.html")
```

Comment: the text file which hyperlinked to `Description` column is  `file:///C:/Users/sharmb5/Documents/SRM_Automation/Output/C415549.txt` (Link is correct). But on clicking the link this display `"Your file was not found."`, what I did wrong in this according to you?

Comment: @Bhavnet Sharma: I will try to reproduce this later.

Comment: @Bhavneet sharma: I couldn't reproduce your error message with Edge. But I can't open files with a full path either. Please run a test in another browser as I assume you are using Edge, too. Please see my answer **Edit:**

Comment: your suggestion helped me a lot and I got knew about `sanitize.text.function`. Thank you so much. !!!